# Embedded Video (Vimeo/YT) Fullscreen not available

Tags: youtube, fullscreen

I got an issue, I am not able to solve with all topics on stackoverflow and github.

I am placing certain Videos via Iframe into my page. Whatever I do, the Fullscreen-Button is greyed out. By clicking, I get the message "Fullscreen not available". Same happens with Vimeo Vids, where the Fullscreen button doesnt appear. Same happens on IOS, Mozilla, Android & Chrome.

I tried to solve it via all the commands, I found here. "allowfullscreen", "allowFullScreen", "allowFullScreen="True"" allowFullScreen='true' mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen allowFullScreen, ...
It seems, that my page itself prevents the fullscreen-mode. If I put my Iframe into clean HTML5-sheets outside my wordpress page, everything works perfectly.

My iframe:

```
<div class='youtube-container-100' allowFullScreen='true' mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen allowFullScreen>
<iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/-mzrMWL5sYQ?rel=0&modestbranding=1' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Putting the iframe without the div doesnt change anything.

I created a testpage: https://my-sushiparty.de/testseite/

Thank you so much :-)

I tried to solve it via all the commands, I found here. "allowfullscreen", "allowFullScreen", "allowFullScreen="True"" allowFullScreen='true' mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen allowFullScreen, ...
It seems, that my page itself prevents the fullscreen-mode. If I put my Iframe into clean HTML5-sheets outside my wordpress page, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube can disable fullscreen view on embedded videos. The "allowFullScreen" command used to work, but it was probably fixed recently.

I've also tried looking for a script that could re-enable the feature, but unfortunately it seems that the latest patch doesn't have a current workaround.